# Can not concatenation network drive

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation

The script that I am working is involve for me to concatenation user input in order to map a network drive. I have tried importing subprocess and OS but I have not had any success.

Below I have listed an example of my code using the subprocess module.

```
import re
import subprocess

# Disconnect anything on M
subprocess.call(r'net use z: /del', shell=True)
#subprocess.call(r'net use z:', shell=True)

sending = input("Enter sending: ")
sending = sending.lower()

distribution = 'c0d'
service = 'c0s'

if re.match(sending[:3], distribution, flags=0):
   subprocess.call(r'net use z: \\+sending+-DB-00\fake_name\rce\help', shell=True)
   print("working distribution center")

elif re.match(sending[:3], service, flags=0):
    print("working service center")
else:
    print("try again")
```

Sorry I forgot to put in the error I was getting
Error:
System error 53 has occurred.

The network path was not found.

I have verified that they path that I am trying to map to exist

Comment: any success? means? what is the output you're getting?

Comment: `r'net use z: \\+sending+-DB-00\fake_name\rce\help'`, let me guess, this should be `r'net use z: \\' + sending + r'-DB-00\fake_name\rce\help'`? Because as is, you're not doing any concatenation, you are using the literal string `'+sending+'`

Comment: subprocess.call(r'net use z: \\'+sending+'-DB-00\-DB-00\\fake_name\\rce\\help', shell=True)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your needs correctly, but if you want to concatenate user input from `sending` variable into shell command you should move it outside quotes:

```
import re
import subprocess

# Disconnect anything on M
subprocess.call(r'net use z: /del', shell=True)
#subprocess.call(r'net use z:', shell=True)

sending = input("Enter sending: ")
sending = sending.lower()

distribution = 'c0d'
service = 'c0s'

if re.match(sending[:3], distribution, flags=0):
   subprocess.call(r'net use z: \\'+sending+r'-DB-00\fake_name\rce\help', shell=True)
   print("working distribution center")

elif re.match(sending[:3], service, flags=0):
    print("working service center")
else:
    print("try again")
```

Comment: When I take concatenation out of the single quotes. This seems to have corrected the issue. Thank you bezet